# Why the access token has changed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

Why the Access Token of our app has changed?

It was in the form: ###|###|###  (with 3 parts) and suddenly today is the this way:

AAACD9oBeLSkBAHtsL1ExLErBoR2clBrNFbI0K3Ei6y1Rd6mXZAoc5fowPVNFT7YKDELTZBCrnNZB45P1pYtzxghV8xd2EwWeFGL4J2dPwZDZD

What happen?????

Comment: FB access tokens have looked like that for a while. Perhaps access via the old method was finally cut off today?

Answer (score 2):

Encrypted access tokens were auto enabled as part of the OAuth 2.0 changes. You can read about it on the developer roadmap. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Comment: The switchover happened on oct 1. You will need to keep an eye on the FB roadmap in the future, it isn't uncommon for FB to introduce "breaking changes" like this.